# Why doesn't VS2017 include librdkafka on Publish nor in the setup/msi of a deployment project

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2017, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I'm trying to deploy a completed .NET 472 Windows Service application which makes use of the

> Confluent.Kafka (1.4.3)

nuget package. In VS2017 the Nuget creates a Debug/Release subdirectory called:

> librdkafka with two subdirectories x64 and x86

.  When I either Publish or use a deployment project (vdproj) none of the x64 and x86 dlls are copied to the publish directory nor included in the "Detected Dependencies" for the project. Is there something I'm missing that would prevent the dlls from the librdkafka to not get placed into the publish directory nor detected in the vdproj?

> Is there some way to get these included into the publish directory or
>   into the detected dependencies on the vdproj?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, but with VS2019 and Confluent.Kafka 1.5.3. In my situation, I have the Confluent.Kafka and librdkafka.redist Nuget packages referenced in a library project and am referencing the library project from a separate service project. The Setup project (.vdproj) is associated with the service, not the library.

I was able to get the MSI generated by the service's Setup project to correctly populate the output directory with the librdkafka DLL's by adding the librdkafka.redist (https://www.nuget.org/packages/librdkafka.redist/) Nuget package as a reference in the service project directly.